# what is the difference between "=" and "=>" when string initializing

Tags: c#, string, operators

i just need to know what is the difference between these two lines

```
private string somestring => "string";
private string somestring = "string";
```

what is the difference of there uses they just prints same to the console

Comment: "=>" does not initialize a string. Instead, it specifies "somestring" as a property returns "string".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
private string somestring => "string";
```

This is an [expression-bodied property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members#properties), and is equivalent to the following:

```
private string somestring { get { return "string"; } }
```

Whereas the following is just a regular [field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields):

```
private string somestring = "string";
```

See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295104/what-is-the-difference-between-a-field-and-a-property) on Properties vs Fields for more information.

Comment: oh thanks so that means it is a readonly didn't figured it out thanks again

Comment: @YonalJayasinghe Yes, but note that if you want read-only _fields_, it's also possible to create one of those using the `readonly` keyword.